# Array rotation problem - not able to get desired output

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, rotation

I wrote a code to rotate an array of size n by d elements. I used temp array to solve the problem. But I am getting different output.There is syntax error in my code. Can anyone help me?
Code:

```java
public static void rotate(int a[], int d, int n) {
    int temp[] = new int[n];
    for (int i = d; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n - 2; j++) {
            temp[j] = a[i];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < d; i++) {
        for (int j = n - 2; j < temp.length; j++) {
            temp[j] = a[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("result is");
    for (int k = 0; k < temp.length; k++) {
        System.out.println(temp[k]);
    }
}
```

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int size, d;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter size");
    size = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("enter rotate count");
    d = sc.nextInt();
    int a[] = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        a[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }
    rotate(a, d, size);
}
```

**Input**:

> enter size 7
>
> enter rotate count 2
>
> input array a[]=1 2 3 4 5 6 7

**Output I got:**

> 7 7 7 7 7 2 2

**Expected output:**

> 3 4 5 6 7 1 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is incorrect, you should not have double loops anywhere, they break everything and there is absolutely no reason to have them logically.

```
for(int i=d;i<a.length;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<n-2;j++){
        temp[j]=a[i];
    }
}
```

What this is does is that every element in `temp` will have the value of `a[a.length - 1]`. All iterations of the outer loops will be completely overwritten by the last iteration of the outer loop at which point `i` will be `a.length - 1`, then you iterate over most of the `temp` and overwrite all their values with `a[a.length - 1]`. You misuse `i` and `j` and the `-2` should probably be `-d` if anything.

There are generally two ways do to this: manually wrapping the index around the array bounds or using the modulo operator to do the wrapping for you. Using modulo is the cleaner approach and I will therefore show that one:

```
public static void rotate(int a[], int rotate){
    int temp[]=new int[a.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        temp[i] = a[(i + rotate) % a.length];
    }
    
    System.out.println("result is");
    for (int k = 0; k < temp.length; k++){
        System.out.println(temp[k]);
    }
}
```

which you then call via `rotate(a,d);`

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your code by using one *for loop* and one *if statement*. Shift *the far* elements to the beginning of the array and shift *the near* elements to the end of the array:

```java
public static void rotate(int[] arr, int d) {
    int[] temp = new int[arr.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (i < arr.length - d) {
            // shift the far elements to
            // the beginning of the array
            temp[i] = arr[i + d];
        } else {
            // shift the near elements
            // to the end of the array:
            temp[i] = arr[i + d - arr.length];
        }
    }
    // replace the contents of the array
    // with the contents of the temp array
    System.arraycopy(temp, 0, arr, 0, arr.length);
}
```

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
    rotate(arr, 2);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    // [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2]
}
```

---

<sup>See also: [Rotating an int Array in Java using only one semicolon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65433410/14838237)</sup>